# How to get shell to a running custom linux container

Tags: linux, docker, kernel, tty, lxc

I am developing a container launcher by referring to https://gist.github.com/zserge/4ce3c1ca837b96d58cc5bdcf8befb80e.

When I launch /sbin/init process using the container launcher I get the tty console for the same.
I am implementing some application for my small hardware where I want to run this container at startup. I am able to launch the container at startup but its ttyS0 console get mixed with the ttyS0 console of my hardware.

1. I want to be able to attach a console to the running container similar to what we can do by **lxc-attatch**.
2. How should I make sure the container's "sbin/init" does not use ttyS0 and use some other tty

Edit:

1. I have my own rootfs similar to lxc container's.
2. My rootfs has /sbin/init process which I want to launch from this container launcher.

Comment: If you think it should be running an init process and it should have a serial port, that sounds like you're looking for a virtual machine and not a container.  Docker containers typically don't have init processes or interactive consoles; they are just wrappers around single processes.

Comment: I agree. Docker is meant for creating application containers. What you want is an OS container, like LXC you mentioned in your question.

Comment: Hello @DavidMaze and KonradBotor Yes, I am trying to launch the OS container. I have my own rootfs similar to lxc container's rootfs. I have /sbin/init process in it which I want to launch.

Comment: Containers like LXC use PTY to emulate the console/terminals for the containers. The ttys in the container are bind mounts on ptys created on host side. So, prior to creating the container, the launcher must create a set of ptys on host side, create ttys and console in the /dev of the container's rootfs and bind mount the latters onto the ptys. Then after the pivot_root in the container, all the ttys/console will be redirected to the ptys on host side.